# How can I find the hazard rate of a time-dependent accelerated failure time model

Tags: stochastic-processes

Suppose I have the following accelerated failure time model:

$t = \exp(-\beta t)u$

where 
the c.d.f of $u$, $F_u(x) = \dfrac{x}{1+x}$.

I tried the following way:

$u = t\exp(\beta t) = \Psi(t)$, or $t = \Psi^{-1}(u)$

$F_t(x)=Pr(t \leq x) = Pr(\Psi^{-1}(u) \leq x) = Pr(u \leq \Psi(x))$

$F_t(x) = F_u(\Psi(x)) = \dfrac{\Psi(x)}{1+\Psi(x)}=\dfrac{x\exp(\beta x)}{1+x\exp(\beta x)}$

The p.d.f of $t$ is: 
$f_t(x)=\dfrac{(1+\beta x)\exp(\beta x)}{(1+x\exp(\beta x))^2}$

The problem is, when $\beta$ is a negative parameter, $1+\beta x <0$ is possible, and we may end up with a negative p.d.f!

I know there must be something wrong with my procedure, just don't know where.